# when i select multiple checkbox in p:datatable selected list is empty

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have followed this link in using the selection of mutiple values in p:datatable

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Now when i select mutiple values from it and click on the button in my form it should call a method in the bean which is working fine.But the selected values list is empty. I read the posts here and oucld not figure out the solution.I also tried different ways but did not work out.

JSF Code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{deviceController.devicesModel}" var="deviceList" widgetVar="deviceTable" selection="#{deviceController.selectedDevices}>                       
<p:column  sortBy="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}" filterBy="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Manufacturer Serial No"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}" />  
</p:column>
<p:column selectionMode="multiple">
 <f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListLaptopTitle_inService}"/>
</f:facet>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable> 
<p:commandButton action="#{deviceController.update(deviceController.selectedDevices)}" value="Submit Request" style="margin-top: 20px"/>
```

Code in Bean:

public String update(List updateDevice) {

```
    try {

        for(Device d:updateDevice)
        {
        getFacade().edit(d);
        }
       //message which indiactes device update is successful
        return "/example.html";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handling exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

So from the page I am passing the value of deviceController.selectedDevices which is empty when checked.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Make sure your managed bean is at least `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: <p:dataTable value="#{deviceController.devicesModel}" var="deviceList" widgetVar="deviceTable" selection="#{deviceController.selectedDevices}>                       
<p:column  sortBy="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}" filterBy="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Manufacturer Serial No"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{deviceList.manufacturerSerialNum}" />  
</p:column>
<p:column selectionMode="multiple">
 <f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListLaptopTitle_inService}"/>
</f:facet>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>

Comment: Sorry I am new to using this tool so dint know how to format my code...

Comment: In the controller I have something like what is defined in the link i gave above my bean,model and the xhtml are similar to what is shows in this link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: I could resolved the issue i added rowKey attribute in the p:datatable.But when I replace the functionality of the button to call the bean instead of the dialog then it returns an empty list.Can you let me know how I can do that,I want the values to be passed to my managed bean.

Comment: Please click the edit button on your _original_ and post both your xhtml code and your bean code.

Comment: public String update(List<Device> updateDevice) {
        
        try {
            
            for(Device d:updateDevice)
            {
            getFacade().edit(d);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("META-INF/Bundle").getString("DeviceUpdated"));
            return "/views/HardwareManagement";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("META-INF/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

Comment: Please find my code..I am not able to format my code...you can find the html in the below comment...

Comment: <p:commandButton action="#{deviceController.update(deviceController.selectedDevices)}" value="Submit Request"/>

Comment: Just edit your question and post both your Facelets (JSF) code and your Java code. Do not worry about the formatting, somebody will edit it and format it for you.

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted my jsf and java code.